# MASM 14: constant expected in winextra.inc

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019, masm, masm32

There is an opinion on the Internet that these errors are a trouble in MSVC 2019. However I not found how to solve this problem except advice to install another version of MASM.

`winextra.inc` from include:

```
; ...
STD_ALERT struct
    alrt_timestamp dd ?
    alrt_eventname WCHAR  [EVLEN + 1] dup(?)  ; Here is A2026
    alrt_servicename WCHAR [SNLEN + 1] dup(?) ; Here is A2026
STD_ALERT ends
; ...
```

So how to solve errors A2026 in winextra without reinstallation MASM to another version?

Comment: Look up what values `EVLEN` and `SNLEN` have and substitute the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of MASM accepted the syntax.
The newer versions require replacing the square brackets with parentheses.

```
; ...
STD_ALERT struct
    alrt_timestamp dd ?
    alrt_eventname WCHAR  (EVLEN + 1) dup(?)  ; Corrected
    alrt_servicename WCHAR (SNLEN + 1) dup(?) ; Corrected
STD_ALERT ends
; ...
```