# Masm not assembling my win32 program in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Guys I been trying to asssemble my masm32 file in visual studio but the build fails each time. there isn't an issue with my program as it runs on other machines perfectly well it's only i think a problem with dependecies or sth or me not runnning this asemmbly file on some older windows version I guess but i tried everything peraps you could point me out to what the problem is

here is the output I get when I try to build it

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug|Win32 ------
1>  Assembling childWnd.asm...
1>C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc(9722): error A2026: constant expected
1>C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc(9723): error A2026: constant expected
1>C:\Project1\childWnd.asm(80): warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced : hPrevInst
1>C:\Project1\childWnd.asm(80): warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced : CmdLine
1>C:\Project1\childWnd.asm(80): warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced : CmdShow
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(70,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\childWnd.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TachildWnd.asm" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

PS: i did put my project folder inside my masm32 directory and it continues to fail

here is the code for my program

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
ClassName db "SimpleWinClass",0
AppName  db "Our First Window",0
MenuName db "FirstMenu",0
ButtonClassName db "button",0
ButtonText db "My First Button",0
EditClassName db "edit",0
TestString db "Wow! I'm in an edit box now",0

.data?
hInstance HINSTANCE ?
CommandLine LPSTR ?
hwndButton HWND ?
hwndEdit HWND ?
buffer db 512 dup(?)                    ; buffer to store the text retrieved from the edit box

.const
ButtonID equ 1                                ; The control ID of the button control
EditID equ 2                                    ; The control ID of the edit control
IDM_HELLO equ 1
IDM_CLEAR equ 2
IDM_GETTEXT equ 3
IDM_EXIT equ 4

.code
start:
    invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL
    mov    hInstance,eax
    invoke GetCommandLine
    mov CommandLine,eax
    invoke WinMain, hInstance,NULL,CommandLine, SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    invoke ExitProcess,eax

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE,CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
    LOCAL msg:MSG
    LOCAL hwnd:HWND
    mov   wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov   wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW
    mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc
    mov   wc.cbClsExtra,NULL
    mov   wc.cbWndExtra,NULL
    push  hInst
    pop   wc.hInstance
    mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_BTNFACE+1
    mov   wc.lpszMenuName,OFFSET MenuName
    mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName
    invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov   wc.hIcon,eax
    mov   wc.hIconSm,eax
    invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW
    mov   wc.hCursor,eax
    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc
    invoke CreateWindowEx,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,ADDR ClassName, \
                        ADDR AppName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,\
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,\
                        300,200,NULL,NULL, hInst,NULL
    mov   hwnd,eax
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd
    .WHILE TRUE
        invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg,NULL,0,0
        .BREAK .IF (!eax)
        invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
        invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg
    .ENDW
    mov     eax,msg.wParam
    ret
WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE
        invoke CreateWindowEx,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, ADDR EditClassName,NULL,\
                        WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or WS_BORDER or ES_LEFT or\
                        ES_AUTOHSCROLL,\
                        50,35,200,25,hWnd,8,hInstance,NULL
        mov  hwndEdit,eax
        invoke SetFocus, hwndEdit
        invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL, ADDR ButtonClassName,ADDR ButtonText,\
                        WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
                        75,70,140,25,hWnd,ButtonID,hInstance,NULL
        mov  hwndButton,eax
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_COMMAND
        mov eax,wParam
        .IF lParam==0
            .IF ax==IDM_HELLO
                invoke SetWindowText,hwndEdit,ADDR TestString
            .ELSEIF ax==IDM_CLEAR
                invoke SetWindowText,hwndEdit,NULL
            .ELSEIF  ax==IDM_GETTEXT
                invoke GetWindowText,hwndEdit,ADDR buffer,512
                invoke MessageBox,NULL,ADDR buffer,ADDR AppName,MB_OK
            .ELSE
                invoke DestroyWindow,hWnd
            .ENDIF
        .ELSE
            .IF ax==ButtonID
                shr eax,16
                .IF ax==BN_CLICKED
                    invoke SendMessage,hWnd,WM_COMMAND,IDM_GETTEXT,0
                .ENDIF
            .ENDIF
        .ENDIF
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam
        ret
    .ENDIF
     xor    eax,eax
    ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Comment: The first two errors (in winextra.inc)  may be related to newer versions of MASM being more selective about some syntax. This other question/answer might be related/a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71579808/masm-14-constant-expected-in-winextra-inc . A fix to winextra.inc is in the answer.